# Complex Printing task support for .net 4

Tags: c#, .net, printing, system.printing

I have been looking for tools which will allow to send documents (pdf,txt,doc,etc) to network printer.

I am aware of the PrintDocument, Graphics to print text to Printer. what I am looking for is easy and less noise solution to achieve it

i.e.

```
using(printer p = new XPrinter)
{
  p.filename = "C:\\1.txt";
  p.printername ="\\network1\mainprinter";
  p.print();
}
```

Are there any open source or 3rd party tools available to ease printing in dotnet 4.. winform/wpf.
or any ideas to achieve it.

**EDIT**
Ideally I want to install this printing application on server and then complete print requests on network printer as requested.

Answer (score 2):

Formatting complex document types like .pdf and .doc for a printer is *not* something you'd want to get into.  You'll need gobs of software to even read the file, let alone format it.  And it is invariably pointless, the user will already have the native application that handles the file format installed on her machine.  Microsoft Office, Adobe Reader, etc.

There's a standard protocol in Windows to get files printed.  You use the Process and ProcessStartInfo classes.  Set the filename to the path of the file, the Verb to "Print".  Process.Start() that, the native app will print the document.  Same thing you get when you right-click the file in Explorer and click Print.

Comment: Process.start will not allow me to change printer  settings. is it? Can IPP be used here instead of standard windows protocol... i am not sure  how to progres sthis further

Comment: It is up to the app to change printer settings, it is doing the printing.  No idea what IPP might mean.  If you mean IPC then, no.

Comment: internet printing protocol.  do you have a example to change printer settings using process.

Comment: People print documents across the Internet?  Isn't it kind of a long walk to pick up the paper?  First I heard of it.  From what I see in the TechNet docs it is purely HTML based.

Comment: I want server Service  to print on user's machine. so i want to chnage printer name for every user

Answer (score 0):

According to other posts, it seems like http://itextpdf.com/ seems to be a good option. I have not used it so I would not if it is good or not. HTH.